# Why is there a copy construct in the following code, considering that all parameters are passed by reference

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::function;
using std::vector;


struct A {
  A(int a){
    
    m_a = a;
    cout<<"cons A"<<m_a<<endl;
  }
  A(const A& a) {
    m_a = a.m_a;
    cout<<"copy cons A"<<m_a<<endl;
  }
  int m_a;
};

int main() {
  function<void()> a;
  vector<A> vec = {12,4};
  for (auto& it : vec) {
    [&it] () {
      it.m_a++;
    };
  }
}
```

Why is there a copy construct in the following code, considering that all parameters are passed by reference

Comment: please do not remove includes and using declarations from the code. It does not make the code easier to read or understand. It does make it more difficult for others to compile the code, and strictly speaking it makes it impossible to know for sure what code you are compiling

Comment: Here `vector<A> vec = {12,4};` creates 2 temporaries and then copies them into the vector - live - https://godbolt.org/z/EW1ffdoPY .

Comment: A side note: your `for` loop body does not actually execute the lambda. You need a `()` suffix for that (`[&it] () { it.m_a++; }();`).

Comment: the loop body make zero sense anyway. and it's pretty clear remove it doesn't effect the behavior, then you should remove it to produce [mcve].

Answer (score 5):

The line

```
vector<A> vec = {12,4}
```

causes two copies.  A `std::vector<T>` has a constructor to take a `std::initializer_list<T>`.  You provide a `std::initializer_list<int>` to a `std::vector<A>` so the `std::initializer_list<int>` is used to create a `std::initializer_list<A>` and then the vector constructor copies the elements of the `std::initializer_list<A>` into the vector.  The reason it copies is that `std::initializer_list<T>` stores `const` objects and those can't be moved or elided out.

---

If you want to remove the copies you can directly construct the member of the vector like

```
vector<A> vec;
vec.reserve(2);
vec.emplace_back(12);
vec.emplace_back(4);
```

which does one memory allocation and two direct constructions.  You can wrap this in a factory function like

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto make_vector(Args&&... args)
{
    std::vector<T> temp;
    vec.reserve(sizeof...(Args));
    (temp.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
    return temp;
}
```

and then when you use it in your code like

```
int main() {
  vector<A> vec = make_vector<A>(12, 4);
  for (auto& it : vec) {
    [&it] () {
      it.m_a++;
    };
  }
}
```

the output is

```
cons A12
cons A4
```